# CameraCalibration with Open CV

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I try to calibrate a camera with python and opnecv. 
I use a video-file instead of a webcam live stream.

Everything seems to work except of the last step. This is:

```
print "now get ready, camera is switching on"
while(1):
    image=cv.QueryFrame(capture)
            t = cv.CloneImage(image);
    cv.ShowImage( "Calibration", image )
    cv.Remap( t, image, mapx, mapy )
    cv.ShowImage("Undistort", image)
    c = cv.WaitKey(33)
    if(c == 1048688):       # enter 'p' key to pause for some time
        cv.WaitKey(2000)
    elif c==1048603:        # enter esc key to exit
        break

print "everything is fine"
```

There I receive following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "V:\Studenten\Christian_Fuerstenhoefer\02_Kamerakalibrierung\openCV\camCalib.py", line 137, in <module>
    t = cv.CloneImage(image);
TypeError: Argument 'image' must be IplImage
```

I already checked print type (image). Then it says None.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does it show at least one image? say the first one?

Answer (score 0):

you don't check for the end of the stream ( each video has an end..)

```
while(1):
    image=cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    if image==None:
        break
```